# How to set up an optional method interception with Ninject?

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, aop, ninject-interception

Suppose I have a class in which I want to sometimes* (but now always) intercept some (but not all) methods. The way I understand it, this can be done either with, say, `InterceptAround()` in my Ninject module (in the higher-level code), or with an InterceptAttribute-derived attribute on those methods (at the implementation level).

I don't really like the first way of doing it, because it requires the consumer to know the details, there'll be many classes with many methods. But I don't like the second way either, since I don't see how to disable (or, rather, not to enable) the interception, as the attribute is fused with the code.

Is there some known approach to solve this problem?

---

*: for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds as though you are referring to an ordinary dynamic interceptor, which is how the Ninject Interception extension works by default.

Here's an example of a conditional interception:

```
class CustomInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Request.Method.Name == "MethodToIntercept")
            Console.WriteLine("Intercepted!");
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

You bind it directly to a single class like so:

```
public class MyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IFoo>().To<MyFoo>().Intercept().With<CustomInterceptor>();
    }
}
```

And that's pretty much all you have to do if you want to dynamically intercept a single class.

The kernel extensions *look* promising because they let you write conditions directly into the declaration:

```
kernel.Intercept(ctx => ctx.Request.Service == typeof(IFoo))
    .With<CustomInterceptor>();
```

However, this isn't particularly useful if you're trying to make decisions based on the *method* being executed, because this only gives you access to the binding context, and not the invocation. Mainly, this extension exists so that you can choose which *classes* or *services* (as opposed to *methods*) to intercept at runtime.

Better to stick to the binding syntax, and write the run-or-don't-run logic directly into the interceptor, as illustrated in the first example.

One important thing to note is that a dynamic interceptor will actually run for *every* (public / virtual) method on whichever class it is bound to, which can be very inefficient.  Unfortunately, the Ninject Interception extension has to take a lowest-common-denominator approach because it is designed to support multiple proxy libraries.  If you use Castle directly, you can [use proxy generation hooks and interceptor selectors for fine-grained control](http://docs.castleproject.org/%28S%28kwaa14uzdj55gv55dzgf0vui%29%29/Default.aspx?Page=Use-proxy-generation-hooks-and-interceptor-selectors-for-fine-grained-control&NS=Tools&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), which is actually the recommended approach. As far as I can tell from the Ninject-DP2 source code, this is not supported with the Ninject extension.

Personally, I've never had a lot of success with the Ninject Interception extension for exactly this reason, and tend to stick to using Castle DP2 directly.  However, if you're doing this on a small scale and aren't writing a performance-sensitive app, you should be fine writing dynamic interceptors.

Comment: I'm accepting this as it gave me an idea of placing a custom attribute on those methods I want to intercept, then checking their presence in my `IInterceptor`, which basically solves my first issue. The use of `IInterceptor` also allows to conditionally enable interception in the module class, which solves the second one. _Dynamic interceptor will actually run for every ... method_ is a concern, but I'm mostly network-bound, so I guess I'll see how it goes.