# Actionfilter equivalent for methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

Is there an `ActionFilter` equivalent for methods in c# itself?

In controllers you can have a custom filter which does a task `OnActionExecuted` and `OnActionExecuting` but i'd like to do a similar thing on methods inside a class as well.

So i'd like to do:

```
[MyMethodFilter]
public static string Convert(string source)
{
     //DO STUFF
     //RETURN A STRING
}
```

The `IActionFilter` interface is part of `System.Web.Mvc`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for aspect-oriented programming. There are some ways to do it in C#:

1. Proxy-class derived from your class. It is easy to do with DI-container:
   [How to set up an optional method interception with Ninject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040235/how-to-set-up-an-optional-method-interception-with-ninject)
2. MSIL Rewriting. Much more complicated technology. PostSharp is a good library to start with it:
   http://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception

So, there is no a ready-to-use `ActionFilter` equivalent. Howewer you can achieve similar functionality.